Springer's Linear Algebraic Groups: Proposition 2.4.4 (Jordan decomposition)
In Springer's Linear Algebraic Groups, he stated the following proposition.
Proposition 2.4.4. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ and let $a \in \text{End}(V)$.

If $W \subset V$ is an $a$-stable subspace of $V$, then $W$ is also stable under $a_s$ and $a_u$ where $a = a_s + a_n$ (additive Jordan decomposition of $a$) and $a\vert_W = a_s \vert_W + a_u \vert_W$ is the additive Jordan decomposition of the restriction $a\vert_W$. A similar result holds for the endomorphism of $V/W$ induced by $a$;

Let $\phi : V \to W, b \in \text{End}(W)$ be linear maps. If $\phi \circ a= b \circ \phi$ then $\phi \circ a_s = b_s \circ \phi, \phi \circ a_n = b_n \circ \phi$.


In his proof of (4), he stated that $\phi$ has a factorisation
$$V \to V \oplus W \to W,$$
where the first map $v \mapsto (v, \phi(v))$ is injective and the second map is projection, a surjective map. He mention that 'an easy argument shows that it suffices to prove (4) if $\phi$ is either injective or surjective and these cases are taken care of by (3).'
I can't seem to understand how is it sufficient to assume $\phi$ is injective or surjective from the above factorisation of $\phi$.
